# Cannot find the Repository bean in Spring boot / Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, spring

I have created a spring project which has a controller and all of its logic is written in Service Interface, which is implemented by ServiceImpl class. I have a repository with which has a model.

```
//Service Interface

public interface Service{
List<Model> getAllKpiData();
}


//ServiceImpl Class
@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements Service{

@Autowired
private KPIRepository kpiRepository;

@override 
private List<Model> getAllKpiData()
{
this.kpiRepository.findAll();
//gets me an empty list.

}
}

//KPIRepository

@Repository
public interface KPIRepository extends MongoRepository<KPIModel, String>
{
}


//Another Service Interface in another package
public interface AnotherService{
List<Model> getAllKpiData();
}

//ServiceImpl Class
@Service
public class AnotherServiceImpl implements Service{

@Autowired
private KPIRepository kpiRepository;

@override 
private List<Model> getAllKpiData()
{
this.kpiRepository.findAll();
//gets me list of values, which are inside the repo(master data).
}
}
```

Both of them are pointing to same repo, but in AnotherService class i am able to get values inside the repository, whereas i am not able to get any values inside Service, on doing this.kpiRepository.findAll().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you have `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` dependency on classpath? If yes, then is KPIRepository in the same package as your main class? If not then in your main class put this annotation `@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses=KPIRepository.class)` to safely tell Spring Data MongoDB to scan a different root package by type if your project layout has multiple projects and its not finding your repositories. Or you can use `@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.acme.repositories.mongo")` to specify the package that contains all of your repositories.

The presense of spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb will automatically enable `@EnableMongoRepositories`. And Spring will automatically create proxies of all classes implementing `Repository<T,ID>` (your class implements MongoRepository, which itself implements Repository) and create beans of them and make them available for injection. And when your repository is in a different package then it is unable to create proxies for your repositories, hence fails to create beans for them. And since there are no beans, it cannot inject them, hence you see the error.

Comment: Well my KPiRepository is in different package, so what do i do now, but the same thing has worked for different package, i mean, same implementation but different packaging

Comment: @SatyaRam, for that add `@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses=KPIRepository.class)' to main class please. It should work after that.

Comment: It worked like a magic, but inside ServiceImpl, i am using this.kpiRepository.findAll(), i am getting an empty List, i already have some values in my repository why is it giving an empty list. I have use the same repository in other package. My repository is in shared library, and i have two other class in different package, which will update values in the repository, In my first class, i am able to get data from repository using repository.findall() wheare as in the above class impl, i am not able to get previous values

Comment: I really don't know what could be wrong. You already mentioned that data is present in the database. So this rules out database being empty. Does `KPIModel` has @Entity or @Document annotation? Do all the fields map to columns? I am fishing here. I myself is not sure what could be wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Did you use the @EnableMongoRepositories annotation? Take a look to this link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html. Review the "6.2 usage" point.

Regards

Comment: It worked like a magic, but inside ServiceImpl, i am using this.kpiRepository.findAll(), i am getting an empty List, i already have some values in my repository why is it giving an empty list. I have use the same repository in other package. My repository is in shared library, and i have two other class in different package, which will update values in the repository, In my first class, i am able to get data from repository using repository.findall() wheare as in the above class impl, i am not able to get previous values